# The button color in Javascript will not change? see setHoverColor & setNormalColor. Also print function (printTimetable) does not reset

Tags: javascript, html

````
Javascript code
```js
````

// Selecting button element

```
var btn       = document.querySelector('#myBtn');
var userInput = document.querySelector('#user-input');
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var body      = document.querySelector('body');

var monday    = ['ECO323','IFS353','MAN305','IFS362'];
var tuesday   = ['IFS353','MAN305'];
var wednesday = ['ECO341','IFS353','MAN303'];
var thursday  = ['IFS353','MANN305','STA302'];
var friday    = ['No Class! Yay! :)'];
```

// when hover over button change color

```
function setHoverColor() {
  btn.style.background ='#DC143C';
}
```

// when not hovering restore to normal setHoverColor Basic Issue: the button color doesn't change. This was resolved by including a set of {} thank you @TechySharnav

```
function setNormalColor() {
  btn.style.background ='';
}
```

//Assign event listeners to the button

```
btn.addEventListener('mouseover', setHoverColor);
btn.addEventListener('mouseout', setNormalColor);
btn.addEventListener('click', printTimetable);
```

//Issue: when a day of the week is written in the input field, it retrieves the subjects for the day, however when another day is used it just adds the subjects for the new day to the bottom of the earlier day used, so not looping correctly, also the image is not retrieved.

```
function printTimetable()

{
```

//Mondays Timetable

```
  if(userInput.value=="Monday")
  {
  for (var i = 0; i <  monday.length; i++) {

    var paraText = document.createElement("p");
    var paraNode = document.createTextNode (monday[i]);
    paraText.appendChild(paraNode);
    container.appendChild(paraText);
    }

  }
```

//Tuesday's Timetable

```
  if(userInput.value=="Tuesday")
   {
  for (var i = 0; i < tuesday.length; i++) {

    var paraText = document.createElement("p");
    var paraNode = document.createTextNode (tuesday[i]);
    paraText.appendChild(paraNode);
    container.appendChild(paraText);
    }

   }
```

//Wednesday's Timetable

```
if(userInput.value=="Wednesday")
 {
for (var i = 0; i < wednesday.length; i++) {

  var paraText = document.createElement("p");
  var paraNode = document.createTextNode (wednesday[i]);
  paraText.appendChild(paraNode);
  container.appendChild(paraText);
  }

 }
```

//Thursday's Timetable

```
if(userInput.value=="Thursday")
 {
for (var i = 0; i < thursday.length; i++) {

  var paraText = document.createElement("p");
  var paraNode = document.createTextNode (thursday[i]);
  paraText.appendChild(paraNode);
  container.appendChild(paraText);
 }

 }
```

//Friday's Timetable

```
if(userInput.value=="Friday")
 {
for (var i = 0; i < friday.length; i++) {

  var paraText = document.createElement("p");
  var paraNode = document.createTextNode (friday[i]);
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  paraText.appendChild(paraNode);
  container.appendChild(paraText);
```

/*ensure that you have an image saved to the correct path with the name
"friday-meme.jpg"  else code will not run correctly*/

```
imag.src="friday-meme.jpg"
  paraText.appendChild(paraNode);
  contianer.appendChild(paraText);
  paraText.style.cssText="font-size:24px;"
  body.appendChild(img);
   }
  }
```

}

````
```
HTML code
```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JavaScript</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<h1>JavaScripts interaction with HTML is handled through events</h1>
<br>
<div id="container">
  <input id="user-input" type="text" name="day" value=""        
  placeholder="Enter a day of the week">
  <br><br>
  <button id="myBtn">Generate Timetable</button>
</div>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```
````

Comment: `function printTimetable()` is invalid ... there's no body to the function - for future reference, learn to use the browser developer tools console

Comment: _...won't work..._ What exactly does that technically mean?

Comment: Hi! 
Please describe the spesific error you encounter and let us know what you expect to happen. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to write a good question.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Write a title that summarizes the actual problem + [mcve]

Comment: When you ran the code, what happened? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Thank you all...I will read up on how to ask a good question. @flimm I expected the button to turn orange

Comment: Why not a simple `:hover` rule: `#myBtn:hover { background-color: #DC143C }` ?

Comment: Just a side note: as JavaScript is case sensitive, `'monday'` is not the same as `'Monday'` and you cannot rely on the fact that a user will type the week name all lower-case and without spelling mistakes. In a case like this, when you have a defined number of options for the user to select, it would be better to use a `<select>` element rather than a text input.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a `}` bracket at the end. It should be `function printTimetable(){ ... }`.

---

Edit: I have structured your code properly, and left comments at certain places of what is being done.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("#myBtn");
var userInput = document.querySelector("#user-input");
var container = document.querySelector("#container");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

let timetableDiv = document.querySelector(".titmetable");   //It will be good if you use separate div for displaying the timetable

let timeTableObject = {
  monday: ["ECO323", "IFS353", "MAN305", "IFS362"],
  tuesday: ["IFS353", "MAN305"],
  wednesday: ["ECO341", "IFS353", "MAN303"],
  thursday: ["IFS353", "MANN305", "STA302"],
  friday: ["No Class! Yay! :)"],
}   //Create an Object of timetables for each day. 

function setHoverColor() {
  btn.style.background = "#DC143C";
}

function setNormalColor() {
  btn.style.background = "orange";
}

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", setHoverColor);
btn.addEventListener("mouseout", setNormalColor);
btn.addEventListener("click", printTimetable);

function printTimetable() {
  timetableDiv.innerHTML = "";           //Reset the Timetable
  let day = userInput.value;
  day = day.toLowerCase().trim();       //Convert user input to lowercase string and trim ut any trailing white spaces

  if (day in timeTableObject) {         //Check if day exists in the timeTableObject (to avoid errors)
    let tt = timeTableObject[day];      //get the timetable for that day
    if (day === "friday") {             //Handle the case of friday separately. 
      var paraText = document.createElement("p");
      paraText.style.cssText = "font-size:24px;"
      var paraNode = document.createTextNode(tt[0]);
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/c1/15/62/c115621542b5330a755797c8acbc152b.jpg"; //Replace this with src of your image
      timetableDiv.appendChild(img)
      paraText.appendChild(paraNode);
      timetableDiv.appendChild(paraText);
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < tt.length; i++) {
        var paraText = document.createElement("p");
        var paraNode = document.createTextNode(tt[i]);
        paraText.appendChild(paraNode);
        timetableDiv.appendChild(paraText);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>

  <h1>JavaScripts interaction with HTML is handled through events</h1>

  <br>

  <div id="container">
    <input id="user-input" type="text" name="day" value="" placeholder="Enter a day of the 
    week">
    <br><br>
    <button id="myBtn">Generate Timetable</button>
    <div class="titmetable"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: _"**when hover** over button **change color**"_ - Why should OP change the color to orange when the mouse leaves the button?

Comment: @Andreas OP said _**when not hovering** restore to normal setHoverColor. The **button color doesn't change**_. In the comment section, OP said he expected button to turn orange.

Comment: Setting `.background = ""` should revert the change to `#DC143C` so changing `""` to `"orange"` would only change the color but not the behavior.

Comment: @TechySharnav Thank you...though it worked on the snipet you sent on stackoverflow.  For some reason its still not showing on my system as orange on mouse out even after making the change

Comment: @TeeToe Did you added the function body? You were missing a pair of `{ }` on the `printTimetable` function.

Comment: @TeeToe Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @TechySharnav yes thank you there was a } bracket missing.

Comment: The other issue is the function printTimetable does not reset after outputting the subjects as required. i.e.,  when a day is input it retrieves the subjects from the time table for that day, but, when another day is written in the input field, it just adds new subjects to the previous days list. Also the image for friday (friday-meme) does not appear when friday is typed in

Comment: @TeeToe Please check the updated answer. I have left comments in the code that will help you out.

Comment: @Andreas Will you please consider to lift the downvote? The main problem of OP has been solved by this Answer.

Comment: Why? The answer is still not correct. You wrote _"You need to set orange as background color..."_ and the actual solution is _"...there was a } bracket missing"_

Comment: @Andreas Oh come on. At least now?

Comment: @TeeToe Can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you?

Comment: @TechySharnav Thank you so much...you helped me so much I learned alot. Thank you for the comments you thoughtfully placed to explain how the updated code worked. Incidentally whether "orange" or "" is used a color change occurs which is all that was needed. Thank you for making this experience worthwhile...many say stack overflow can be 'scary' for those new to coding...much appreciated!